# How can I replace a merge module with a <file>?

Tags: dll, windows-installer, installshield, merge-module, winsxs

I had a problem installing my project on vista and 7 which I mentioned before here.

[How to cope with Install error 1920 about winsxs merge modules in Vista and 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617689/how-to-cope-with-install-error-1920-about-winsxs-merge-modules-in-vista-and-7)

I see that post for a problem may be similar of mine, and there is a solutuion author tried.
[comctl32.msm (Merge module) Fails on Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496299/comctl32-msm-merge-module-fails-on-vista)

I want to replace my .dll files to winsxs folder in vista or 7 can I do that? If I can how?

Regards,

togikan